# How do I write a Clojure macro to create more than one expression?

Tags: macros, clojure

Is it possible to write a macro in Clojure that generate more than one value or expression?
For me it looks like it's not possible, at least not by using the syntax quote template `(..).

e.g. from: `[1 4]` via `[1 (mr 2 3) 4]` to `[1 2 3 4]`

or from:

```
(do
  (prn 1)
  (prn 4))
```

via:

```
(do
  (prn 1)
  (mr 2 3)
  (prn 4))
```

to:

```
(do
  (prn 1)
  (prn 2)
  (prn 3)
  (prn 4))
```

Answer (score 10):

A macro expands one form into another form, so you can't have a macro return two completely independent forms. However, you can have it return compound forms like `do` statements that do a bunch of things.

```
(defmacro foo [n]
  `(do ~@(map #(list println %) n)))
```

For your example above you can put the macro around the form you wish to modify:

```
(expand-mr
 (do 
   (prn 1)
   (mr 2 3)
   (prn 4)))
```

macros are designed to be safe and as such they can't modify anything outside of their own scope. Currently a macro gets an s-expression, and changes it into another more useful or helpful s-expression. In order for a macro to return two separate s-expressions it would have to modify its enclosing expression. The syntax would have to be radically different and I'm not clear how this would be done with s-expressions. The solution of this is to expand the scope of the macro to include everything it needs to modify.

Comment: Thanks Arthur! I was already expecting that answer, but it's nice to be sure.

Comment: But can you actually give me an example how a macro returning two independent forms can cause a security problem, but is safe otherwise? I think the scope is still the same.

Comment: I'm using the term 'safe' loosely sorry about that. I'll edit to expand on that.